# Numpy import error when running .py file from windows command line using python executable file

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, exe, importerror

I've recently written some code to process some data which I need to be done every day at the same time. As a result I researched various methods and attempted to do this using the Windows Task scheduler. For the 'Start a program' field I entered the path to the python.exe file in my computer C:\Users...\Anaconda3\python.exe and in the 'add arguments' field I entered the file path of the .py file I want to be run every day "C:\Users..................\daily_python_file.py". This didn't work so I then I tried to run .py file from the command line using the same paths I entered in the fields of the task scheduler, and received the following error:

```
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\...\...\...\...\...\daily_python_file.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

It works fine to run the .py file when running it from the anaconda prompt command line. I also created a test python file which just contained a print function which ran no problem from the windows command line, (I'm assuming because this .py file has no dependencies (i.e. numpy, pandas etc).  I'm aware that it might have something to do with where the modules are installed (which anaconda environment) but I'm not sure how to turn this into a solution. There are also a few questions similar to this online however I haven't found any concrete solutions.

For some background I am running Windows 10, and in the anaconda base environment python 3.8.5, numpy 1.19.2.

Any help on this matter will be massively appreciated.

UPDATE

I managed to solve this problem using a .bat file. I knew that once the anaconda base environment was activated then the python.exe file would run the .py file in question, so I compiled a .bat as follows:

```
call C:\Users\Stanley\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\...\...\...\...\...\...\daily_python_file.py"
```

Then used task scheduler to run this on a daily basis. The call line activates the base environment and then the python file runs no problem. This doesn't give a reason as to why it didn't work before however it does provide a good alternative.

Comment: I (maybe) had a similar problem with another package. I solved it by adding "C:\Users...\Anaconda3\Scripts\" and "C:\Users...\Anaconda3\Library\bin\" to the system path variable. I think this might be worth a try. The Problem could be that the dlls are found if the Anaconda env is active, but not when you just call the exe. So adding the dlls path to the system variable can solve this. You might want to look up which dll includes multiarray_umath and also add the folder that contains that dll specificly. Note: this is just an idea, I might be completly wrong.

Comment: Did you try to pip install numpy?  (compile it from scratch?)  If you did  STOP now.  delete this environment and create a conda environment and a conda install of numpy.

Comment: Thank you both I tried your solution Jonas and it didn't work unfortunately. And the only environment I have setup on this computer is the base environment which would have had numpy installed at the start so I don't think that it was installed using pip. I did however find a solution which I will post as an update on the original question.